# How to make a bot stop a certain action and not close?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So here's my code.

```
# simple bot.
import random, discord, os, time, ctypes
from xmlrpc.client import MAXINT
from time import sleep
bot_token = "BOT TOKEN"
local_time = time.ctime(time.time())
randnum_bot = discord.Client()
@randnum_bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild_count = 0
    print("""randomnum bot has started running.
Current time: """ + local_time)
    for guild in randnum_bot.guilds:
        guild_count += 1
        print("randomnum bot is in " + str(guild.name))
@randnum_bot.event
async def on_message(message):        
    if(message.content == "!generatenum"):
        random_time_interval = random.randint(0, 5)
        random_times = random.randint(0, 100)
        await message.channel.send(f"A random number will be generated every {random_time_interval} seconds for {random_times} times.")
        for i in range(random.randint(0, 100)):
            await message.channel.send(random.randint(0, MAXINT))
            sleep(random_time_interval)
randnum_bot.run(bot_token)
```

Put simply, this Discord bot generates a random number for a random amount of times within a random interval of time.

But here's the thing: I want to make the bot cease all of its activities(and remain online) once a certain message is sent, for example a `!stop` message.

I tried adding an `elif` in the `on_message` function, and I did it like this:

```
@randnum_bot.event
async def on_message(message):        
    if(message.content == "!generatenum"):
        random_time_interval = random.randint(0, 5)
        random_times = random.randint(0, 100)
        await message.channel.send(f"A random number will be generated every {random_time_interval} seconds for {random_times} times.")
        for i in range(random.randint(0, 100)):
            await message.channel.send(random.randint(0, MAXINT))
            sleep(random_time_interval)
    elif(message.content == "!stop"):
        await message.channel.send("Alright, see you next time!")
        await randnum_bot.close()
```

Although it does make the bot stop once a message that contains `!stop` is sent, it actually makes the bot go offline, which is really inconvenient. I also tried inserting `await randnum_bot.run(bot_token)` after `await randnum_bot.close()`, but that resulted in an error which was `RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop`.

Is there a way to make a bot stop its activities, without actually making it go offline?

Comment: If you use the `commands` extension, you can disable all the commands except `stop` and `resume` once the `stop` command is invoked and then re-enable them with the `resume` command, if you would like. You can also make these two commands for your use only, no other user can invoke them.

Comment: You need to use `await client.start` and then asyncio run it if you want to close the client. Also, be advised that the minimum delay should be at least 1 second, due to ratelimits (and API abuse potentially getting you banned). Also: never use sleep, instead use `await asyncio.sleep(seconds)`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. `.close()` forcefully terminates the connection to discord. If you want the bot to stop responding, you'll have to do something such as setting a flag in the code to ignore all events. I don't know why you would want to do this though.